# Passing variable to php MySQL script with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I borrowed this code from another source.
Now, I am attempting to modify it.

I need to pass the contents of $q to my php page and use this as a where clause in my SQL statement.

**My Javascript:**

```
<script>
  function subject(str) {
    if (str == "") {
      document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = "";
      return;
    } else { 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("subject").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
       }
     }
     xmlhttp.open("GET","form_get.php?q="+str,true);
     xmlhttp.send();
    }
  }
</script>
```

Inside the html select code I am using:
     `onchange="subject(this.value)"`

**My PHP**

```
$q = intval($_GET['subject']);
//if (!empty($_GET['q'])){
  //$q = $_GET['q'];
//}
include('../conn/conn.php');
$sql = "select DISTINCT grade FROM primary_skills where subject= $q ";
```

As you can see, I am passing the $q into my SQL statement.
I understand that intval returns a number, but when I try other types, such as strval, it breaks the script. It als breaks the script when I tried the commented out section above.

When I change the php to: `$q=$_GET["q"];` I get the error: form_get.php?q=Reading 500 (Internal Server Error).
This tells me that $q is indeed pulling from the options list, but something else is going on...

Comment: In your code I don't see how `$_GET['subject']` exist, you probably mean `$_GET['q']`. Also in your SQL you need to use quotes `subject='$q'`. And you have a SQL injection problem. Make sure to escape your string or use PDO.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek intval is ok there is no need to escape once you excepting int

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with your php you suppose to get the q and not subject

```
$q = intval($_GET['q']);

include('../conn/conn.php');
$sql = "select DISTINCT grade FROM primary_skills where subject= $q ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$q = intval($_GET['subject']);
```

This looks wrong - should that not be `$q = intval($_GET['q']);`?

Comment: I changed this to $GET['q'] and get the same results.
When I echo out $q, I get 0 when I should be getting the value of my selected option from the drop down menu.

Comment: did you mean $_GET['q'] or literally $GET['q']?

Also, this sql / php is wide open to sql injection by the looks of things btw

Comment: $_GET['q']. Thank you. I will be sanitizing everything before it goes into production.

Where  $_GET['q'] is returning 0, I need it to return the value of my SelectBox Options.

Comment: well, `intval()` returns a number, 0 if no number is found in the string. If you don't want a number, why do you use intval()?

Comment: I found the solution. I forgot to surround the `$q` with single quotes in the SQL statement. Seems as if the smallest things throw me off. But, I am learning!